# Possible Findbug false positive for "obl_unsatisfied_obligation"

Tags: java, findbugs

I have a code section like bellow:

```
try (UnitOfWork unitOfWork = datasource.getConnection()) {
    ResultSet resultset = untiOfWork.getStatement().getResultSet();
    unitOfWork.queueToClose(resultSet);
    ...
}
```

The UnitOfWork is an AutoClosable. So inside of the `UnitOfWork` `close()` method is like this.

```
@Overide
public void close() {
    for (AutoClosable closable : queueToClose) {
        closable.close();
    }
    connection.close();
}
```

Now the FindBug is complaining about the ResultSet is not being closed. Is this a false positive? Is this a bad pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a false positive in the sense that `ResultSet` will be closed, but there is no way for FindBugs to know this.

It is also a bad pattern: what happens if you forget to call `queueToClose` after getting a `ResultSet`? Does `UnitOfWork.getStatement()` add the statement to `queueToClose` before returning it?

Better would be

```
try (UnitOfWork unitOfWork = datasource.getConnection();
     Statement statement = unitOfWork.getStatement();
     ResultSet resultset = statement.getResultSet()) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the excellent answer that 'Alexey Romanov' posted there is a potential leak in your implementation of UnitOfWork.close where if any of those close calls throws an exception your connection is not closed.

```
@Override
public void close() throws Exception {
    Exception first = null;
    try (AutoCloseable requiredForJdk8 = this.connection) {
        for (AutoCloseable closable : this.queueToClose) {
            try {
                closable.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                if (first == null) {
                   first = e; 
                } else {
                    if (first != e) {
                        first.addSuppressed(e);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (first != null){
            throw first;
        }
    }
}
```